# How do I set listeners on the lower most changes in a firebase database hierarchy

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

We are trying to use Firebase to synchronise contacts between users and between the users and the server.
The FB structure is like this:

```
../contacts
        +phone_number_1
            +contact_id_1
               +name
               +contact_phone
               +…
            +contact_id_2
               +…
        +phone_number_1
```

The server has a ‘value’ changed listener on the top most level. i.e. the “../contacts”.
What we wish is that every change in the lower most level will be delivered to the server:

Examples:

1. contact_id_3 was added,
2. contact_id_1/name was changed

In both cases, ideally, the server would get a callback with a snapshot which contains either the lower most document (that is the ../contact_id) or if not possible, one level above it - the ../contacts/phone_number_1 level.

What we see is that the first contact of a new user added is indeed received like that. From the second contact and on, there is no call back  at all.
Changes are not received either.

Perhaps this is done by design, but how the server suppose to get the change information? Setting a listener on every user is impractical.

The server is node.js and we are using Firebase web API.